# Why aren't the passenger seats designed as jump seats (foldable) in commercial airlines?

Tags: passenger, cabin-design, seats

We know that the crew seats in an airplane are "jump seats (foldable)", which made me wonder why it isn't the same case with passenger seats.

Some advantages which I see if passenger seats are converted to the "jump seat" design:

- Better access and thus easier cleaning of the aircraft
- Easy entry exit by passengers
- Already available tech (as in the crew jump seats)

Comment: Heavier weight, **more expensive**, more maintenance... You'll also notice crew jump seats are attached to a bulkhead (wall) not free standing.

Comment: Jump seats - as in crew foldable seats - are designed to give back space when they're not used. The cost is they are expensive and less comfortable. Making them standard for passenger seats is completely impractical from a cost and design perspective, and as Ron Beyer says, they are attached to a bulkhead: impossible for passenger seats except those up on the bulkhead itself.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You're in luck. Airbus has [filed a patent](https://www.dezeen.com/2014/07/16/airbus-files-patent-folding-airplane-seats/) for that. ([Not a joke](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140159444).)

> Airbus said the design was a response to recent demands from low-cost airlines to cram more seating into existing plane interiors – often to the detriment of passenger comfort.

Just when I thought the below can't get any worse.

[image]
([Original](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3341651/Think-economy-squeeze-Boeing-patents-cramped-12-seating-plan-business-class.html), sardine edit by @TomMcW)

---

There is also [this concept](https://www.today.com/money/new-airplane-seat-patent-could-take-middle-seat-new-low-t31486):

[image]

> Although the patent has been filed, whether or not the seats will become popular depends on whether or not airlines want to pick up the design.

Comment: The good news is that this awful design has oodles of safety issues

Comment: My favorite is the vertical [stacked](https://www.google.com/amp/www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-are-stack-seats-the-next-trend-in-airline-seating-20151009-story,amp.html) followed by the alternating front-back (which I can't find right now)

Comment: Next they'll be installing straps or handrails so you can stand in the aisle like on a bus

Comment: @TOmMcW: [Ryanair tried something similar](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/8779388.stm)

Comment: Don't forget these strange seat design configurations are also likely to slow down evacuation times. With most aircraft at the limit anyway, anything that impacts fast egress will not get past the regulators. Remember this concept (aircraft design that supports fast passenger egress - within 90 seconds) has been a well-known hold up factor for certification of various recent aircraft types.

Comment: @Pete855217: And not-so-recent ones as well - the 747 had some trouble meeting the 90-second requirement at first, primarily due to its upper deck and the inability to use a standard emergency slide therein.

Comment: @Sean, from memory I believe the A380 was held up for ages (a year or two) until they could meet the 90 second evacuation rule. There are few videos on YouTube that show Airbus staff celebrating when they could all escape one of the A380 prototypes in under 90 seconds. After the event, they were all very pleased with it all!